# When is time that AWS S3 object lifecycle rule get executed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle, rules

Want to find out when is the certain time that AWS S3 object lifecycle rule get executed

Have created some objects lifecycle rules. want to find out the time that the rules get executed.

Comment: the time in a day

Comment: Executed the days by the object creation time on the lifecycle policy?

Comment: I have heard some people say that it can take up to 48 hours for a lifecycle policy to execute. So, there might not be a specific time.

Comment: Found out - executed on the day started. not base on creation time.